# Multi-Factor Authentication is not working properly with ASP.NET Core 2.1 Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I've tried to implement a multi-factor authentication for my web application.

I'm able to generate an Authenticator-Key based on my logged-in user. Using Google Authenticator, I'm able to generate a code. The problem come up when I'm validating this code. (It's a time-based code)

For some reason, it seems like my `_userManager.VerifyTwoFactorTokenAsync(...)` doesn't work while the code is not expired, but as soon as the code change in the Google Authenticator app, the same "expired" code is now valid, and I'm now redirected and logged in.

This is my token generator code :

```cs
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

var authenticatorKey = await _userManager.GetAuthenticatorKeyAsync(user);

if (authenticatorKey == null)
{
    await _userManager.ResetAuthenticatorKeyAsync(user);

    authenticatorKey = await _userManager.GetAuthenticatorKeyAsync(user);
}

return View(new RegisterAuthenticatorViewModel { AuthenticatorKey = authenticatorKey });
```

And this is my code validation code :

```cs
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

var isValid = await _userManager.VerifyTwoFactorTokenAsync(user,
                _userManager.Options.Tokens.AuthenticatorTokenProvider, model.Code);

if (!isValid)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Code is invalid");
    return View(model);
}

await _userManager.SetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(user, true);

return View("_Success");
```

Since the code is actually working, my problem is to why it's validating the code only after it expired on the Google Authenticator App.

Comment: The time part of time-based isn't just talking about usable for a certain period of time. The time is core factor in the generated code itself. It's used both in the generation and validation. Based on your problem description, it seems there's some variance between the timing on your server validating the code and client generating the code, i.e. one or the other is off from actual real time.

Comment: I also have same issue with this authenticator. I don't know why the validation code from Authenticator App always invalid. I suspect there is something between AuthenticatorTokenProvider and `[TwoFactorEnabled]` & 
`[EmailConfirmed]`colums in the table `dbo.AspNetUsers`.

@Oley, have you solved this issue ?
@Chris, any comment ?